# functional typescript: error in pipeline converting postgres database results to a view model (fp-ts)

Tags: node.js, typescript, functional-programming, fp-ts

I am trying to retrieve data from a postgresql database, transform it to a view model array and return the data to the client, ideally as a single object in this case rather than an array.  I am getting the following error for the code I have listed beneath the error message.  I am new to the functional programming space and am confused on how to utilize the data transformation concepts?

TS2345: Argument of type ‘(department: {}) => (department: QueryResult) => Department’ is not assignable to parameter of type '(a: {}) => TaskEither<DBError, {}>'.   Type ‘(department: QueryResult) => Department’ is not assignable to type 'TaskEither<DBError, {}>'.

```
type DBError = MultipleResultsError | NoRecordsFoundError | Error;

const retrieveDepartments = async ({departmentId}: {departmentId: number}): Promise<TE.TaskEither<DBError, Department[]>> => {
    const client = await pool.connect();

    try {
        const query = 'SELECT * FROM department where departmentId = ?';
        const res: QueryResult<Department> = await client.query(query, [departmentId]);

        return pipe(
            TE.right(res.rows),
            TE.chain(
                TE.traverseArray(department => mapDepartmentViewModel)
            )
        );
    } catch (e) {
        return TE.left(e);
    } finally {
        client.release();
    }
}

export type Department = {
    departmentId: number,
    departmentName: string,
    departmentSupervisorId: number,
    departmentSupervisorFirstName: string,
    departmentSupervisorLastName: string
}

export const mapDepartmentViewModel = (department: QueryResult): Department => ({
    departmentId: department.departmentId,
    departmentName: department.departmentName,
    departmentSupervisorId: department.departmentSupervisorId,
    departmentSupervisorFirstName: department.departmentSupervisorFirstName,
    departmentSupervisorLastName: department.departmentSupervisorLastName
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`TaskEither<T, E>` is just a type alias for `Task<Either<T, E>>`.

`Task<T>` is a type alias for `() => Promise<T>`.

`retrieveDepartments` actually returns a `Promise<Either<DBError, Department[]>>` since all the return values are `Either`s. Therefore you should change its return type to `Promise<Either<DBError, Department[]>>`.

Note that `retrieveDepartments` itself couldn't be typed as a `TaskEither<DBError, Department[]>` since it requires an argument, and `Task` take none: typed as a task, users won't be able to pass the arguments it actually expects.

Comment: What would the solution be?  Not sure what you mean by "...couldn't be typed as a TaskEither<DBError, Department[]> since it requires an argument, and Task take none".  Could you provide more clarity?  Thanks.

Comment: Edited my post. It's changing the return type to `Promise<Either<DBError, Department[]>>`. As a `Task` users can't pass the arguments that `retrieveDepartments` actually needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
type DBError = MultipleResultsError | NoRecordsFoundError | Error;

export type Department = {
    departmentId: number;
    departmentName: string;
    departmentSupervisorId: number;
    departmentSupervisorFirstName: string;
    departmentSupervisorLastName: string;
};

const retrieveDepartments = async ({
    departmentId,
}: { departmentId: number }): Promise<TE.TaskEither<DBError, Department[]>> => {
    const client = await pool.connect();

    try {
        const query = 'SELECT * FROM department where departmentId = ?';
        const res: QueryResult<Department> = await client.query(query, [departmentId]);

        return pipe(
            TE.right(res.rows),
            TE.chain((departments: Department[]) =>
                pipe(
                    TE.traverseArray(mapDepartmentViewModel)(departments),
                    TE.map((result: Department[]) => result)
                )
            )
        );
    } catch (e: DBError) {
        return TE.left(e);
    } finally {
        client.release();
    }
};

export const mapDepartmentViewModel = (
    department: QueryResult
): TE.TaskEither<DBError, Department> =>
    TE.tryCatch(
        () => {
            const mappedDepartment: Department = {
                departmentId: department.departmentId,
                departmentName: department.departmentName,
                departmentSupervisorId: department.departmentSupervisorId,
                departmentSupervisorFirstName: department.departmentSupervisorFirstName,
                departmentSupervisorLastName: department.departmentSupervisorLastName,
            };
            return mappedDepartment;
        },
        (error: DBError) => error
    );
```

Comment: How would the pipe have to change to accomodate this?

Comment: I´ve edited my answer with the complete code, improving also the error handling inside your `mapDepartmentViewModel` function. I hope I was able to help.